# Time and date issues in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a set of data with date and time. I want to plot time on the y-axis and date on the x-axis, and plot the number of observations at a given time during each day. However, my observations start at around 20.00 on the first day, and end around 06.00 the next day. So, when I plot this, R plots all observations on each date:

[Here is a link to a picture of my current graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddh8h.png)
[image]
Does anyone know how to define the y-axis to start at one date and end at the next date?

Here is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

test$DATE <- as.Date(test$DATE, format = "%d.%m.%Y", tz = "UTC")
test$hms <- format(test$TIME, format = "%H:%M:%S")
test$hms <- as.POSIXct(test$hms, format = "%H:%M:%S")

ggplot(test, aes(test$DATE,test$hms)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth() + 
theme_light() + theme(legend.position="top") +
scale_color_brewer(palette = 1, type = "qual") +
ggtitle("emergence/return time") +
scale_x_date("d",date_breaks="7 days",date_labels="%d-%m")+
scale_y_datetime("Time",breaks=date_breaks("60 min"),labels = 
date_format("%H:%M"))

g <- ggplot(test, aes(test$DATE,test$hms)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth() + 
theme_light() + theme(legend.position="top") +
scale_color_brewer(palette = 1, type = "qual") +
ggtitle("emergence/return time") +
scale_x_date("d",date_breaks="7 days",date_labels="%d-%m")+
scale_y_datetime("Time",breaks=date_breaks("60 min"),labels = 
date_format("%H:%M"))

g + scale_colour_grey()+theme(
panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: So you want to have all times from 20:00 to 6:00 of the next day to count as if they were on the same day?

Comment: If @RuiBarradas is correct, you could omit the `d.m.Y` part of your dates and just keep the `H:M`.

Comment: Yes, @RuiBarradas, that's correct.

Comment: @nate If I omit the d.m.Y in as.Date, and use H:M instead, nothing happens. Is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Exactly, that might be an idea. Depending on your needs and your data, you could delete the `d.m.Y` part and then rescale the  `H:M` part such that 20:00 corresponds to the min. and 06:00 to the max.